# Availability of videoMediaMetadata

Tags: google-drive-api

I use google drive api (via python) and I wonder if there is an exact period of time after uploading video on google drive when i can be sure that videoMediaMetadata exists for uploaded files. Are there any ways to adjust that period of time for our corporate google drive?

According to the documentation (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) videoMediaMetadata field

> This may not be available immediately upon upload

without any additional clarifications.

In my case there are files which were uploaded on the 15 of October and haven't had videoMediaMetadata field yet

Code from comment:

```
service.files().list(fields="nextPageToken, 
                     files(id, name, videoMediaMetadata(width, height, durationMillis), imageMediaMetadata(width, height))").execute()
```

but there is no problem with request because for other files i get videoMediaMetadata successfully

Comment: How do you formualte your request to retrieve this data?

Comment: service.files().list(fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name, videoMediaMetadata(width, height, durationMillis), imageMediaMetadata(width, height))").execute() but there is no problem with request because for other files i get videoMediaMetadata successfully

Comment: Is it only one very specific video that causes you this problem? I this case, maybe there is a problem with the video itself? How soon can you see the metadata for other videos?

Comment: It's for a bunch of them. All files are correct mp4 videos. I see no correlation between uploading date and availability of videoMediaMetadata field, because all of them were uploaded on the same day